# UITextView arrow keys are not working when it is inside UICollectionViewCell on Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, mac-catalyst

When a `UITextView` (or UITextField) is inside a `UICollectionViewCell`, arrow keys don't seem to be working, pressing up/down/left/right won't move the cursor. However, arrow keys with a modifier key (alt/cmd) do work, for example, cmd + left would go to beginning of the line.